# what is exactly Tornado?

Tags: python, cgi, wsgi, tornado, uwsgi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Facebook's new Tornado framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406912/what-is-facebooks-new-tornado-framework)

sorry for that question, but when using a python file on internet, we use: CGI (non supported by Nginx) or WSGI (which is the standard for python) and uWSGI (which Ngnix supports) for Fast-CGI (the CGI with on long process) and SCGI (simple CGI).... but

HOW DO WE CALL TORNADO? what does it use?

Comment: Tornado doesn't run on Apache... it's a separate webserver.

Comment: i dont see why down voting, am asking a technical question, but maybe who downvotes give his arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Already had a look at the documentation ?

[tornado.wsgi — Interoperability with other Python frameworks and servers](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/wsgi.html)

What else do you need to know?

Comment: this is only for compatibility with WSGI, it's not made for, it's an asynchronous and wsgi isent so, but what i wanna know, is what's the name of the protocol that tornado uses